# How to make big Facebook API requests faster?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an Facebook application in PHP that fetches a large amount of location information of the user's friends. The application gets increasingly slow as the number of friends of the users increases. But the more friends' information I retrieve, the more accurate is the result.

I have tried to use the following ways to speed up the query:

```php
$facebook->api('/locations?ids=uid1,uid2,uid3,...')
```

And I used this together with [batched requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/):

```php
$batched_request = array(
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/locations?ids=uid1,uid2,uid3,...'),    
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/locations?ids=uid11,uid12,uid13,...'), 
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/locations?ids=uid21,uid22,uid23,...'), 
    ...
);
$batch = $facebook->api('/?batch='.json_encode($batched_request), 'POST');
```

But still it takes at least **20 seconds** to get the location information from a random set of 100 friends of the user.

### Actual Code Used

This part is fine. It gets done in just a few seconds.

```php
$number_of_friends = "100"; // Set the maximum number of friends from which their location information is retrieved
$number_of_friends_per_request = 10; // Set the number of friends per request in the batch

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

// This is the excerpt of another batched request to get the friend ids
$request = '[{"method":"POST","relative_url":"method/fql.query?query=SELECT+uid,+name+FROM+user+WHERE+uid+IN(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1+=+me()+order+by+rand()+limit+'.$number_of_friends.')"}]';
$post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . "?batch=" . urlencode($request) . "&access_token=" . $access_token . "&method=post";
$post = file_get_contents($post_url);
$decoded_response = json_decode($post, true);
$friends_json = $decoded_response[0]['body'];
$friends_data = json_decode($friends_json, true);
if (is_array($friends_data)) {
    foreach ($friends_data as $friend) {
        $selected_friend_ids[] = number_format($friend["uid"], 0, '.', ''); // Since there are exceptionally large id numbers
    }
}
```

But this is problematic. It takes too long to receive a response from Facebook.

```php
// Retrieve the locations of the user's friends using batched request
$i = 0;
$batched_request = array();
while ($i < ($number_of_friends/$number_of_friends_per_request)) {
    $i++;
    $friend_ids_variable_name = 'friend_ids_part_'.$i;
    $$friend_ids_variable_name = array_slice($selected_friend_ids, ($i-1)*$number_of_friends_per_request, $number_of_friends_per_request);
    if (!empty($$friend_ids_variable_name)) {
        $api_string_ids_variable_name = 'api_string_ids_'.$i;
        $$api_string_ids_variable_name = implode(',', $$friend_ids_variable_name);
        $batched_request[] = array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/locations?ids='.$$api_string_ids_variable_name);
    }
}
$batch = $facebook->api('/?batch='.json_encode($batched_request), 'POST');
foreach ($batch as $batch_item) {
    $body = $batch_item["body"];
    $partial_friends_locations = json_decode($body, true);
        foreach ($partial_friends_locations as $friend_id => $friend_locations_data) {
            $friend_locations = $friend_locations_data["data"];
            foreach ($friend_locations as $friend_location) {
                // Process location information...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the above request faster? I placed some codes to check the response time of the request and it is pretty slow.

- For 100 friends, it takes > 20 seconds on average.
- For 200 friends, it takes > 40 seconds on average.
- For 400 friends, it takes > 80 seconds on average, and I sometimes receive an error message: "Error Code: 1 Message: An unknown error occurred"

To make things faster, it means:

- Getting the **same amount** of information in **less time**, or
- Getting **more information** for the **same amount** of time.

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with batched requests? You can achieve everything with a single FQL multiquery:

```
{
  "my_friends":
    "SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN
      (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 100)",
   "their_locations":
     "SELECT page_id, tagged_uids FROM location_post WHERE tagged_uids IN
       (SELECT uid FROM #my_friends)",
   "those_places":
      "SELECT page_id, name, location FROM page WHERE page_id IN
        (SELECT page_id FROM #their_locations"
 }
```

In the [API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=%7B%0A%22my_friends%22%3A%22SELECT%20uid%2C%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%20ORDER%20BY%20rand%28%29%20LIMIT%20100%29%22%2C%0A%22their_locations%22%3A%22SELECT%20page_id%2C%20author_uid%20FROM%20location_post%20WHERE%20author_uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid%20FROM%20%23my_friends%29%22%2C%0A%22those_places%22%3A%20%22SELECT%20page_id%2C%20name%2C%20location%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20IN%20%28SELECT%20page_id%20FROM%20%23their_locations%29%22%0A%7D), this runs in the 800-1200 ms range for me.

Another question: Why do you have the PHP SDK installed, but aren't using it to make these queries?

Comment: I am more like a novice in Facebook applications development. I will surely try this to see if I can speed up the whole process.

Comment: Ok. I have tried this. It took me 4765-111625ms to receive the response. But this is already faster. However, I received very limited location data, much less than what I can obtain from my batched requests. Does the location information include the ones from photos, checkins, tags, and shared photos and videos? Or can we raise the limit of locations for each of these friends?

Comment: I have improved my connection and can receive the response in 2 seconds. But the reduced amount of information is still an issue.

Comment: I can retrieve information from up to 25 countries using the batched requests but can only get up to 8 countries using FQL. Not sure why. I enabled every permission in the Graph API Explorer.

Comment: I tried to do this:
`"their_locations":
     "SELECT page_id, tagged_uids FROM location_post WHERE tagged_uids IN
       (SELECT uid FROM #my_friends) LIMIT 5000",`
This gets me more information but is taking up more time (still faster than the batched requests). But then when I increased the number of friends, the location information retrieved for each of the friends is reduced again.

Comment: There are limits to what FQL returns. You may find that to get all the data you need you might have to make multiple requests, probably in the background, and refine what your user sees over time.

Comment: The FQL is only faster for retrieving a limited amount of data. It is not very capable of big requests. For a person with over 4000 friends (even with the limit of 100), requesting such location information would return the following error: _This API call could not be completed due to resource limits_. Making requests in the background is not a good option since analysis of information is required before displaying the results to the user.

Comment: @Antony `SELECT page_id, tagged_uids FROM location_post WHERE tagged_uids IN (SELECT uid FROM #my_friends) LIMIT 5000` - This returns an empty set for me. Do you know if the syntax changed? I'm able to extract everything properly with author_uid IN (SELECT uid FROM #my_friends), but that doesn't include posts in which a user is tagged ..

Comment: @TejaswiYerukalapudi Maybe a [Facebook bug](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/394304313967672/)?

Answer (score 0):

I too have noticed that facebook has a slow API response time.  I have not actually developed a facebook application, but perhaps some of my learnings in dealing with the facebook like buttons and comment/share buttons will help you:

What I would suggest, is to lace your page with asynchronous  api calls via javascript to get data.  This way the page loads fast for your user, then it loads the facebook data in the background.  You can accomplish this relatively easily with a library like jquery.  Essentially you will break off the chunk of code that runs to process the data into another file and then run that with the jquery call.

Now that is the first part.  The second part could be a little trick again to allow the user to perceive a faster application load time.  Always load the first 100 friends first and display resulting data, and then query a second time (again using asynchronous calls), to finish querying for the rest of the users friends.

Again, this is speaking from more of a general perspective, but hopefully it will help!

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I am not simply displaying the results to the end user but have to analyze the data to give a useful output. Thus I need to have all the information beforehand.